# Not sure how to map variable to show in app

Tags: javascript, react-native

Here's the function-

```
  const setLoading = (value) => {
  const messages = dashboards.data.message.filter((item) => {
      const title = item.dashboardTitle || item.dashboardName;
      return title.toLowerCase().startsWith(value.toLowerCase());
    });
    setFiltered(messages);
    console.log(filtered);
  };
```

I want to display the variable 'messages' separately in my app, how would I do that? 'messages' variable needs to be displayed within the default react native 'Text' component. I have written down 'messages' below within Text component but currently it's not displaying anything (since it is within function) -

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Keyboard} from 'react-native';
import { Searchbar } from 'react-native-paper';
import { theme } from '../theme';
import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { apiStateReducer } from '../reducers/ApiStateReducer';
import CognitensorEndpoints from '../services/network/CognitensorEndpoints';
import DefaultView from '../components/default/DefaultView';
import DashboardListCard from '../components/DashboardListCard';

const AppHeader = ({
  scene,
  previous,
  navigation,
  searchIconVisible = false,
}) => {
  const [dashboards, dispatchDashboards] = useReducer(apiStateReducer, {
    data: [],
    isLoading: true,
    isError: false,
  });
  const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState([]);

  const setLoading = (value) => {
  const messages = dashboards.data.message.filter((item) => {
      const title = item.dashboardTitle || item.dashboardName;
      return title.toLowerCase().startsWith(value.toLowerCase());
    });
    setFiltered(messages);
    console.log(filtered);
  };
  const dropShadowStyle = styles.dropShadow;
  const toggleSearchVisibility = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Search');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    CognitensorEndpoints.getDashboardList({
      dispatchReducer: dispatchDashboards,
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <View style={styles.headerLeftIcon}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={navigation.pop}>
            {previous ? (
              <MaterialIcons
                name="chevron-left"
                size={24}
                style={styles.visible}
              />
            ) : (
              <MaterialIcons
                name="chevron-left"
                size={24}
                style={styles.invisible}
              />
              )}
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      <Text style={styles.headerText}>
        {messages}
      </Text>
        <View style={styles.headerRightIconContainer}>
          {searchIconVisible ? (
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={[styles.headerRightIcon, dropShadowStyle]}
              onPress={toggleSearchVisibility}>
              <MaterialIcons name="search" size={24} style={styles.visible} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ) : (
            <View style={styles.invisible} />
          )}
        </View>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If your messages variable is an array you can map it

```
{messages.map((message, key)=>(
 <Text style={styles.headerText}>
   {message.dashboardName}
 </Text>  
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your messages variable is stored in 'filtered' state, you can map it by doing this:

```
{filtered.map((item, index) => <Text key={index}>{item.dashboardName}<Text>)}
```